# A protein-coded gene Regular Expression

Tags: regex, parsing, compilation, nsregularexpression

I am trying to write a regex that can match the following instructions
A sequence of character with the “AT” prefix, followed by “nG” where n is a digit from 1 through 5 and then "G" and lastly followed by a suffix of 5 numeric digits.

**Note:** just the ordinary regular expression not language specific.

An example of a matching string is this: “AT1G01040”

Here is what I could construct `AT[1-5]G(d\{1,5})` but I am not sure if it is the correct answer.

Please, I need your hand on this thanks.

Comment: _followed by a suffix of 5 numeric digits_ - do you mean exactly or up to? If exactly, you need `\d{5}`, not `1,5`.

Comment: Some regex engines do not support `\d`, or also match Unicode digits by default, thus, I'd advise to stick to `[0-9]` character class/bracket expression.

Comment: `AT[1-5]G(d\{1,5})` ?? don't you  mean `AT[1-5]G(\d{1,5})`  \d for digits - I'm assuming that's a typo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of digits at the end may be from 1 to 5, you may use

```
^AT[1-5]G[0-9]{1,5}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2yyyT/1).

Note that if the number of digits at the end must be exactly 5, you must remove `1,`:

```
^AT[1-5]G[0-9]{5}$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `AT` - a sequence of chars `AT`
- `[1-5]` - `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `5`
- `G` - a `G` char
- `[0-9]{1,5}` - any 1 to 5 consecutive occurrences of an ASCII digit (or - if you use `{5}` - exactly 5 occurrences)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Hey Wiktor thanks very much for this answer  form my instruction I think this is my right answer.  ^AT[1-5]G[0-9]{1,5}$

Comment: Please If am not off topic, can you also help me with a Non-Deterministic Finite Automaton (NFA) that can recognize these strings ?

Comment: What do you mean? The expression above will validate a string that matches your requirements. If you need to extract them from some longer text, you should replace `^` and `$` with  word boundaries, in most languages, `\b`.